# How to match collection contents in Spock interactions?

Tags: unit-testing, spock

Given I have the following method in a class that I mock:

```
class Foo {
   public void doSomething(Collection<String> input) {
     //...
   }
}
```

Now I mock this class in my Spock test and I want to verify an interaction:

```
def test() {
    setup:
    def myMock = Mock(Foo)

    when:
    def hashSet = new HashSet<String>(['foo', 'bar'])
    myMock.doSomething(hashSet)

    then:
    1 * myMock.doSomething(['foo', 'bar'])

}
```

This interaction however doesn't trigger. What is really strange is that the output is telling me:

```
too few invocations for:

1 * myMock.doSomething(['foo', 'bar'])   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

1 * myMock.doSomething(['foo', 'bar'])
```

So it basically told me that there was no invocation that looked like the one I was expecting but there was another one which ... ermm looked like the one I was expecting.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a limitation of Spock and I need to check the collection contents in a closure like

```
1 * mock.doSomething( { it == ['foo', 'bar'] })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all because an instance of `HashSet` is passed as an argument to mock invocation while an instance of `List` is passed in `when` block. `[]` is an `ArrayList` in groovy - there's a type mismatch - but both `Set` and `List` printed to console look very similar. The following test is working well:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class Test extends Specification {

    def "test"() {
        setup:
        def lol = Mock(Lol)

        when:
        def hashSet = new HashSet<String>(['foo', 'bar'])
        lol.doSomething(hashSet)

        then:
        1 * lol.doSomething(new HashSet<String>(['foo', 'bar']))
    }
}

class Lol {
   public void doSomething(Collection<String> input) {
       println input
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually I would have expected this to work no matter which actual type of collection I am using as the signature of the doSomething method clearly indicates that ANY kind of Collection<String> is allowed, may it be a HashSet, LinkedList, ArrayList or whatever.  I really don't think that it is correct when your API actually specifies that you can use any Collection but your test fails if your collaborator does not use the exact same collection type that you used for setting up your mock.

Comment: In terms of contract defined it works well, the client of the API you created can use any *subtype* of `Collection<String>`, but when it comes to testing  **exact** arguments passed are checked so I disagree with you. If you need to check if an instance of `Collection<String>` is passed try `it instanceof Collection<String>`. Answer yourself what you need to test, acutal data or actual data type? It turns out that it's something different.

Comment: Well in this specific case I need to check the data, I don't care about the type of the collection. So I guess I'll have to stick with the closure. So not exactly a better solution than I have now but at least the discussion has helped me so I'm accepting this answer.